# Javascript runs function only once

Tags: javascript

The

**HTML**

```
<p>What factorial would you want to calculate?</p>
<input id="factorium" type="number">
<input id="submission" type="submit" value="Calculate">
```

**Javascript**

```
function factorial(x) {
    if (x === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
}

    var inputBox = document.getElementById('factorium').value;
    var submission = document.getElementById('submission');
    submission.onclick = function(){console.log(factorial(inputBox))};
```

> Edited -

The submit button only works once, I need to refresh the page for it to work again, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new function that only executes the above code as follows:

```
function getVals(){

    var inputBox = document.getElementById('factorium').value;
    var submission = document.getElementById('submission');
    console.log(factorial(inputBox));
}
```

and on the input submit button I've added:

```
<input id="submission" type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="getVals()">
```

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript code can be reduced to one line:

```
document.getElementById('factorium').value();
```

This is enough to trigger the error. The problem is `.value()`, which should be `.value` instead. As the error message says, `.value` is not a function and can't be called.

Comment: Rats, you *just* beat me to it ;)

Comment: @melopomene - i've re-edited the question, the submit button only works once, it needs to refresh page for it work again, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/16bay4L6/)

```
<p>What factorial would you want to calculate?</p>
<input id="factorium" type="number">
<input id="submission" type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calcFactorial()">

<script>

    function factorial(x) {
        if (x === 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }

        function calcFactorial(){
            var inputBox = document.getElementById('factorium').value;
            var submission = document.getElementById('submission');
            console.log(factorial(inputBox));
        }
</script>
```